# Microsoft.Graph SDK Get members of the group of type 'Group'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to get members of the group of type 'Group' only. Below is the code:

```
var _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(CreateAuthProviderFromSecret(creds));

var applicationsInGroup = await _graphServiceClient.Groups[objectId.ToString()].Members.Group.GetAsync();


public static IAuthenticationProvider CreateAuthProviderFromSecret(GraphCredentials creds)
{
    var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(creds.ClientId)
    .WithTenantId(creds.TenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(creds.ClientSecret)
    .Build();

    return new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
}
```

On running, I see this error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Graph.Community;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "yout_tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "azure_ad_client_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$count", "true")
};
var transitiveMembers = await graphClient.Groups["group_id"].TransitiveMembers.WithODataCast("microsoft.graph.group").Request(queryOptions).Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual").GetAsync();
```

I think you may try my code above : )